# Is there a way to avoid this lighting effect using tile-maps in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework, lighting

### Is there a way to get smooth gradient from the lighting?

I'm creating a survival game using PhaserJs 3. I'm using the LightsManager and a tileset I modified from one of the example tilesets included in the examples.

Currently the tile grid is visible because of how the lighting is working with the tiles.

[image]

If possible, I would like to have the lighting be smooth similar to the picture below:

[image]

My grass tile is 32x32:

[image]

and the normal map is the following image

[image]

which was generated using [this normal map generator](https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/) site.

```js
 var config = {
        type: Phaser.WEBGL,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        pixelArt: true,
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update,
        },
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 0, x:0 },
                debug: false
            }
        },
    };

var light;
var layer;

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('tiles', ['assets/tilemap.png','assets/tilemap_n.png']);

        ...
    }

function create ()
    {

        var level = [ // The grass tile is #29 in the tileset
            [29,29,29,29,29,29],
            [29,29,29,29,29,29],
            [29,29,29,29,29,29],
            [29,29,29,29,29,29],
            [29,29,29,29,29,29],
            [29,29,29,29,29,29]]

        var map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 32, tileHeight: 32 });

        var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
        layer = map.createStaticLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0).setScale(2)
        layer.setPipeline('Light2D');

        light = this.lights.addLight(390,223.3, 150).setIntensity(.8);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best (or most performant) way, but you could use [this plugin](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/shader-kawaseblur/) to create a post *pipeline blur*.

here a working demo of this plugin: https://codepen.io/rexrainbow/pen/zYzzYVw

Basically you would have to load the plugin, in `preload`:

```
   function preload (){
       ...
       this.load.plugin('rexkawaseblurpipelineplugin', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexkawaseblurpipelineplugin.min.js', true);      
   }
```

And apply the plugin in to the specific camera, or *gameobject*:

```
function create (){
    var postFxPlugin = this.plugins.get('rexkawaseblurpipelineplugin');
    var postFxPipeline = postFxPlugin.add(this.cameras.main, {
        blur: 1,
        quality: 3
    });
    ...
}
```

**Or you could fake**, the gradient with multiple lights and may be add a specific ambientColor:

```
light1 = this.lights.addLight(390,300, 150, 0xffffff, .80);
light2 = this.lights.addLight(390,300, 250, 0xffffff, .75);
light3 = this.lights.addLight(390,300, 350, 0xffffff, .70);
this.lights.enable().setAmbientColor(0x555555);
```

Comment: Maybe, although I don't want to blur my pixel art. Thanks though!